# Get current user inside register_rest_route method

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

How to retrive wp_get_current_user() inside a register_rest_route callback (Wordpress site)?

I'm just trying to do a simple hello wp_get_current_user()->user_login on a php test page:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'helloTest');

function helloTest() {

    register_rest_route('hello', 'hello/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'showHello'
    ));
}

function showHello($someVariable) {
    echo "Hello " . wp_get_current_user()->user_login . $someVariable;
}
```

But wp_get_current_user() is null and wp_get_current_user->ID is 0;

I dont want to authenticate the user again. I just want to retrieve his username. If he is not logged in, just show empty an empty string.

If I have to authenticate again, how to add a "nonce" to it? On internet I just have examples using javascript, but not directly on PHP methods.

Comment: The REST API Handbook [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), "*If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an **unauthenticated request**, even if you’re logged into WordPress.*" So use *cookie authentication* (e.g. by using the `X-WP-Nonce` header) or try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) or other [authentication plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins).

Comment: As I said: "On internet I just have examples using javascript, but not directly on PHP methods."

Comment: There are PHP and JS examples given on the [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) and also by the [JWT auth plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) author.

Comment: But anyway, are you making the API request from and to the same WordPress site? How are you making the request - using JS, Postman, a non-WordPress site, or? Can you add the code which you use to *make* the request? (the current code in your question is just for delivering a response to that request)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Theres no "code" that make the request. Its is just an anchor that calls my route: <a href="site.com/wp-json/hello/?John">Hello</a>

Comment: So, have you checked the answer? Does it help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues in your code

First off, you should understand properly how to [add custom WP REST API endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/):

1. An endpoint's *namespace* (the first parameter passed to `register_rest_route()`) should be in this format: `your-plugin/v<version>`. E.g. `hello/v1` or `hello-world/v1` and not just `hello` or `hello-world`.
2. `$someVariable` (the first parameter passed to your endpoint callback function) is not just any variable — it's an instance of the [`WP_REST_Request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/) class — and shouldn't be `echo`-ed like what you did here:

   ```php
   function showHello($someVariable) {
       echo "Hello " . wp_get_current_user()->user_login . $someVariable;
   }
   ```

   And normally, the *$someVariable* is better be changed to `$request` (i.e. rename it to "request").
3. And you should return a valid WP REST API response. For example, to return just the username:

   ```php
   return new WP_REST_Response( wp_get_current_user()->user_login, 200 );
   ```
4. And know your own API endpoint URL..

   ```
   (based on your original namespace)
   /wp-json/hello/hello/1  <- correct
   /wp-json/hello/?John    <- incorrect
   ```

   because in your code, the parameter is a number and not string: `(?P<id>\d+)`

I hope those help you, and once again, do read the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for a more detailed guide.

#### The Corrected Code

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'helloTest' );

function helloTest() {
    register_rest_route( 'hello/v1', 'hello/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'showHello'
    ) );
}

function showHello( $request ) {
    return new WP_REST_Response( wp_get_current_user()->user_login, 200 );
}
```

### Now about getting the user (from the API endpoint — `showHello()`)

> If I have to authenticate again, how to add a "nonce" to it?

Just because the user is logged-in/authenticated to the (WordPress) site, it doesn't mean the user is automatically logged-in to the WP REST API. So yes, you'd need to either provide a nonce along with your API request, or use one of the authentication plugins mentioned [right here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins).

Now in most cases, `GET` (i.e. read-only) requests to the API do not need any authentication, but if you'd like to retrieve the data of the currently logged-in user on your site, then one way is via the `_wpnonce` data parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests).

Example for a GET request:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_wpnonce=<nonce>
```

So based on your comment *and the corrected code (above)*:

> Theres no "code" that make the request. Its is just an anchor that
>   calls my route: `<a href="site.com/wp-json/hello/?John">Hello</a>`

You can add the nonce as part of the URL *query string* like so: (the namespace is `hello/v1` and the `<id>` is `1`)

```php
// Make request to /wp-json/hello/v1/hello/<id>
$nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
echo '<a href="/wp-json/hello/v1/hello/1?_wpnonce=' . $nonce . '">Hello</a>';
```

So try that out along with the corrected code and let me know how it goes. :)

And once again, be sure to read the REST API authentication [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).